# abort other uploads on-first-server-validation-fail-response

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I need to stop all other uploads if the server responded with some error. 
Fine-uploader has property stopOnFirstInvalidFile=true which does that, but this stands for client side validation whereas I need aborting depended on the server response. 
Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

To cancel all uploads, use [the `cancelAll` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#cancelAll).